# Showing the desktop version of a fully responsive website on tablets

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

How does one go about creating a fully responsive site (ie. 'fluid') that *doesn't* end up displaying the narrow "mobile" version on a tablet? (Usually the mobile version of a website is designed with thumbs in mind. It's very basic, usually single column, and isn't really suited to larger mobile devices like tablets.)

Even if you've designed everything to scale gracefully to every width, you still need the `viewport` setting to tell a user's phone to display the content at the right width... but this setting appears to also be honoured by tablets, too.

I realise you can use a detection solution (like [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)) but then it's not really fully fluid (although I suppose you could use Mobile Detect to insert a `viewport` meta tag if a mobile phone is detected). Is there a better way to get tablets to display the desktop version?

I feel like I'm missing a very obvious trick!

Comment: You could use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

**How it should work when adopted into the CSS standards:**

Use @media queries in CSS, along with the @viewport CSS tag, instead of the meta viewport tag. There's a good explanation of how to do this here:

http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/

An example from the above link:

```
@media (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  @viewport {
    width: 640px;
  }
}
```

You could use this to set different viewports on narrower and wider devices.

**But for now, seems JavaScript is the only way to do it:**

You can listen to the onResize event and check the width of the screen, and then adjust the viewport meta tag in the DOM accordingly.

See http://www.webdevdoor.com/responsive-web-design/change-viewport-meta-tag-javascript

Comment: Aha! That's the missing part of the puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be supported anywhere useful at present...?? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-deviceadaptation

Comment: Sorry, I agree, not useful at the moment. This is the way it's supposed to work. Meanwhile, my only suggestion is to detect browser resize in JavaScript and modify the meta viewport tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries for different sized screens, ie: small(phones), medium(tablets), and desktop versions.  You will only change the content thay needs changed in the queries. Then also set a meta tag with the viewport set at 1.0. Search around for media queries, there's a lot of information of there. Good luck!