# WebView - Displaying a Responsive Site as Desktop

Tags: android, html, mobile, webview, desktop

Perhaps a typical and well-trodden question on first glance. But all other answers I've looked at (there are many) have consistently suggested (almost always) changing the user-agent of a WebView to a desktop string. Consistently, people have responded that this does not work for them. Myself included.

As a web design novice, from what digging I have done it seems that at some point in the last few years "responsive design" became the recommended and most widely used web design implementation philosophy of choice to determine how to deliver/display a site.

Which is why I believe changing a user-agent of a WebView is having no effect, as the site seems to be determining how to deliver content based on the meta tag "viewport", for example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0">
```

Has anyone else overcome this yet? Would my (layman) analysis of the issue be correct?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding, i think this seems like the below situation

Please look into this answer [Showing the desktop version of a fully responsive website on tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866988/showing-the-desktop-version-of-a-fully-responsive-website-on-tablets)

Answer (score 0):

So I think I may have found a solution, in part due to @hussnain-muavia answer, though there was slightly more I had to expand which I thought would warrant its own response.

---

### WebView Settings

The WebView will need to be able to execute JavaScript:

```
WebSettings settings = _webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

In order for the site to be completely zoomed-out (i.e. displaying the full site and without scrollbars) additional settings will have to be applied to the WebView:

```
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setInitialScale(1);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

---

### Achieving a Desktop Layout

Ultimately the thing that will result in a desktop view is the following JavaScript:

```
function desktopMode() {
    var viewPort = document.getElementsByName("viewport");
    if (viewPort != null) {
        viewPort = viewPort[0];
    }
    else if ((viewPort = document.getElementById("viewport")) == null) {
        return;
    }
    viewPort.setAttribute("content", "width=" + (screen.width + 1) + "; initial-scale=0.5");
}
```

As I mention in my question, I am a web design novice. Though one thing I notice is inconsistency (sorry web devs?) so I've intentionally built in a check by name *and* ID. We should expect only one tag, hence why name assumes the zeroth element.

Further to this solution I found I was getting a desktop layout but not quite the complete thing. So I modified the calculation thusly:

```
    getViewport.setAttribute("content", "width=" + (screen.width * 4) + "; initial-scale=0.5");
```

I don't like it. But it works. My suspicion is there probably is some better calculation or constant for this.

---

It's probably worth mentioning, it's still worthwhile changing the user-agent string, in case the site does not use a responsive design. But this is an unrelated topic.

---

A major drawback of this solution is that it will result in some hideous UI, where the user can see the site being resized. As I put the JS in onPageStarted, but of course the functionality gets overridden. So I put it after the super onPageStarted call or in onPageFinished and this results in the same result of the user seeing the resize happening. Any ideas out there?